# Disabling Custom Appearance For MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

When the user inputs a name into the recipients portion of MFMessageComposeViewController, the  recipients bar, turns black and vanishes. The user can still send a message, input text and do all the other stuff, they just can't see the recipients bar.

I have a feeling that this may (or may not) be because the navigation bar of the MFMessageComposeViewController is customized (background image and custom font).

**1. My navigation bar's custom appearance is set for the entire app, how do I disable it for the MFMessageComposeViewController?**

**2. Could there be any other reason for this glitch? Is it an iOS7 bug?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**So yes, the problem here was because I was using the UIAppearance proxy for UINavigationBars**.

So what solved this problem?

Rather than trying to change MFMessageComposeViewController, which is more of an app on its own, I customized my own app.

Rather than using `[UINavigationBar appearance]`, I used `[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[SomeNavigationController class], nil]`

I think this is really simple if you can do this, because trying to customize  MFMessageComposeViewController can be pretty annoying.

Everything above applies for MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: i cant change the text color, i tried doing this:
        [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMailComposeViewController class], nil] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMailComposeViewController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMailComposeViewController class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: I don't think iOS allows you to change the colour of the MFMailComposeViewController (since it is a system-based view controller) directly using appearanceWhenContainedIn

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem and here is my solution-

Before presenting your message composer( `[self presentViewController:messageComposer animated:YES completion:nil];` )
 set

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

and in delegate method

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller
                 didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
     UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Navigation Bar"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Thats all!!